# Qt problems building on Mac OS X 10.7.5 with Qt 4.8.1 using QSerialPort

Tags: macos, qt, build

So I have a project that I have been working on. Currently I am able to build it in Linux and Windows without too much trouble. I am having some issues on Mac, however.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.5, with Qt 4.8.1.

I installed the libraries for QSerialPort since those are not included in Qt4. It looks like they installed correctly. My /qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib folder now includes:

```
libQtSerialPort_debug.1.0.0.dylib
libQtSerialPort_debug.1.0.dylib
libQtSerialPort_debug.1.dylib
libQtSerialPort_debug.dylib
libQtSerialPort_debug.prl
```

When I try to build the project this is what I get:

```
Starting /Users/ken/esu_2.x/esu/esu.app/Contents/MacOS/esu...
dyld: Library not loaded: libQtSerialPort_debug.1.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/ken/esu_2.x/esu/esu.app/Contents/MacOS/esu
Reason: image not found
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/Users/ken/esu_2.x/esu/esu.app/Contents/MacOS/esu exited with code 0
```

Edit:

```
apples-MacBook-Pro:macOs ken$ otool -L esu
esu:
    libboost_system.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libQtSerialPort_debug.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /Users/ken/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.1)
    /Users/ken/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.1)
    /Users/ken/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/QtNetwork (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.1)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1094.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Moved QtSerialPort libraries to /usr/lib. It works now.